# jQuery on change submits data before being loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am making a ajax request on a dynamically added element.
My purpose is to change the image that has just been uploaded and added dynamically on the page (the image has a change button).
Issue I am facing here is that after the ajax request PHP returns that no file is sent .i.e form is submitted before file was loaded with browse.

I cannot add submit button as only one button should be present.

Screenshot for UI (event is tied up on change button)

[image]

which is dynamically added by clicking and uploading that + button on the right (same change event is fired and it is working fine for that event).

Code:

```
$('.img-holder').on("change",".upload_form_change",function(){
    /*var file = _("file_new").files[0];
    var formdata1 = new FormData();
    formdata1.append("file_new", file);
    var ajax = new createXMLHTTPObject();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", changeCompleteHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php");
    ajax.send(formdata1);*/

    var currentEle = $(this);
    console.log('fired');
    $.ajax({
      url: "file_upload_parser.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: new FormData(),
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data){
        //currentEle.html(img);
        console.log('success');
      }
    }, 1000);

  });
```

Commented section is what I am using on + icon ajax upload.

PHP

```
<?php
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
    echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    exit();
}
if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "test_uploads/$fileName")){
    echo "$fileName upload is complete";
} else {
    echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
}
?>
```

output array in response when adding `echo print_r($_FILES);` at top

```
 Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Penguins.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => E:\xampp\tmp\php3C47.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 777835
        )

)
```

Error that is being returned in post

```
Notice: Undefined index: file1 in E:\xampp\htdocs\file_upload_parser.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: file1 in E:\xampp\htdocs\file_upload_parser.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: file1 in E:\xampp\htdocs\file_upload_parser.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: file1 in E:\xampp\htdocs\file_upload_parser.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: file1 in E:\xampp\htdocs\file_upload_parser.php on line 6
ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.
```

HTML that is being appended

```
<div style="margin-bottom:10px; position: relative;" class="col-lg-4 text-center item">
<form class="upload_form_change" style="position:absolute;position: absolute;z-index: 9999;width: 71px;left: 40%;top: 36%;opacity: 0;" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" class="change-upload" name="file_new" id="file_new" value="&#43;">
</form><img src="test_uploads/'+ imageFileName[0] + '" alt="" class="img-thumbnail small">&nbsp;
<button class="btn btn-small btn-change"><a href="">Change</a>
```

Ignore the CSS

How can I debug this ?

Comment: can you post your HTML please?

Comment: Hint: `contentType: 'multipart/form-data'`

Comment: var fd = new FormData();    
fd.append( 'file', input.files[0] );  then pass fd to ajax request as data.   check this answer :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery

Comment: @messerbill HTML added

Comment: @RanjeetSingh Nope, didn't work

Comment: so try to echo your `$_FILES` at first line in your PHP script to have a look if its filled or not (think you should use smth like `echo print_r($_FILES);`

Comment: @messerbill yes, I am getting the response and filename in it but still not working...any idea why ?

Comment: can you please update your question with the output of `$_FILES` ?

Comment: @messerbill added, please have a look.

Comment: This is very silly mistake of mine...if you will notice I am using wrong input name for file. I have used "file1" instead of "file_new" which I am adding dynamically. Thanks for your help anyways :)